# How to make a html tag expand as much as possible to fit the parent width?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to make a textfield in my html page to expand as much as possible to fit the parent width.  Here is an image shows what I want.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ez2learn.com](http://static.ez2learn.com/temp/css-problem.PNG))</sub>

I try to use width: 100%, but the browser sets the width of elemnt as its parent's, which makes no room for other elements, they have to to be placed in second line.  How can I let the element to expand as much as possible to fit all space in single line?

Thanks.

Comment: The code is here http://paste.plurk.com/show/278739/

Comment: The left sidebar is a left-float div, with 200 fixed pixel. And the right container is another div but not floated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the input ‘100% minus the widths of those other things’ you're into CSS layout stuff.

You could `float: left` the label, `float: right` a wrapper around the buttons, and set left and right margins on a wrapper around the input, then set the input to `width: 100%`.

(But personally, liquid-layout forms is one of the places I still typically resort to tables, as combining a series of fixed- and variable-width columns is something that easily stretches CSS layout beyond its limits.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bobince. I would look into a table option. I would either decide on fixed:width that works for you within the table, or try to make the width:100% within the table.